# Unable to make DELETE sql query

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I am unable to make the DELETE query to delete that extra row in the table [Inventory_Databases_Master] as below:

```
SELECT SQLInstanceName,DatabaseName
FROM [AdminInventory].[dbo].[Inventory_Databases_Master]
where SQLInstanceName='SMLYNSQL01NOD01'
```

--Returns 26 rows
SMLYNSQL01NOD01             DB1
SMLYNSQL01NOD01             hi
SMLYNSQL01NOD01             DB2
SMLYNSQL01NOD01             DB3
SMLYNSQL01NOD01             DB4
SMLYNSQL01NOD01             DB5
SMLYNSQL01NOD01             DB6
SMLYNSQL01NOD01             DB7
SMLYNSQL01NOD01             DB8
SMLYNSQL01NOD01             DB9
SMLYNSQL01NOD01             DB10
SMLYNSQL01NOD01             DB11
SMLYNSQL01NOD01             DB12
SMLYNSQL01NOD01             DB13
SMLYNSQL01NOD01             DB14
SMLYNSQL01NOD01             DB15
SMLYNSQL01NOD01             DB16
SMLYNSQL01NOD01             DB17
SMLYNSQL01NOD01             DB18
SMLYNSQL01NOD01             DB19
SMLYNSQL01NOD01             DB20
SMLYNSQL01NOD01             DB21
SMLYNSQL01NOD01             DB22
SMLYNSQL01NOD01             DB23
SMLYNSQL01NOD01             DB24
SMLYNSQL01NOD01             DB25

```
SELECT SQLInstanceName,DatabaseName
FROM [AdminInventory].[dbo].[Inventory_Databases_DailyUpdate] D
WHERE D.RunNumber=(SELECT MAX(RunNumber) from [Inventory_Databases_DailyUpdate])
and SQLInstanceName='SMLYNSQL01NOD01'
```

--Returns 25 rows
SMLYNSQL01NOD01             DB1
SMLYNSQL01NOD01             DB2
SMLYNSQL01NOD01             DB3
SMLYNSQL01NOD01             DB4
SMLYNSQL01NOD01             DB5
SMLYNSQL01NOD01             DB6
SMLYNSQL01NOD01             DB7
SMLYNSQL01NOD01             DB8
SMLYNSQL01NOD01             DB9
SMLYNSQL01NOD01             DB10
SMLYNSQL01NOD01             DB11
SMLYNSQL01NOD01             DB12
SMLYNSQL01NOD01             DB13
SMLYNSQL01NOD01             DB14
SMLYNSQL01NOD01             DB15
SMLYNSQL01NOD01             DB16
SMLYNSQL01NOD01             DB17
SMLYNSQL01NOD01             DB18
SMLYNSQL01NOD01             DB19
SMLYNSQL01NOD01             DB20
SMLYNSQL01NOD01             DB21
SMLYNSQL01NOD01             DB22
SMLYNSQL01NOD01             DB23
SMLYNSQL01NOD01             DB24
SMLYNSQL01NOD01             DB25

The below DELETE query is deleting 0 records. I need to delete that record with DatabaseName as hi.

```
DELETE M
FROM Inventory_Databases_Master M
LEFT JOIN Inventory_Databases_DailyUpdate D (NOLOCK)
ON M.SQLInstanceName=D.SQLInstanceName
AND M.DatabaseName=D.DatabaseName
WHERE D.RunNumber=(SELECT MAX(RunNumber) from 
[Inventory_Databases_DailyUpdate])
AND D.DatabaseName IS NULL
```

Please help !

Comment: Can you show the records being returned? I'm thinking that this condition `AND D.DatabaseName IS NULL` is causing the issue. Since you don't have that in either of the queries above.

Comment: Query result updated in original question. Thank you for your time.

Comment: If remove "AND D.DatabaseName IS NULL", then all 25 rows are getting deleted from Inventory_Databases_Master and the only row left is with DatabaseName as "hi". However, I need opposite that these 25 rows should remain and only the "hi" row should get deleted.

Comment: Then change `AND D.DatabaseName is NULL` to `AND D.DatabaseName = 'hi'`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your query won't find any records to delete because if `D.DatabaseName` is `NULL` then `D.RunNumber` will also be `NULL`.

Is it the following you need:

```
DELETE M
FROM
    Inventory_Databases_Master M
    LEFT JOIN Inventory_Databases_DailyUpdate D (NOLOCK) ON
        M.SQLInstanceName = D.SQLInstanceName
        AND M.DatabaseName = D.DatabaseName
WHERE D.DatabaseName IS NULL
```

Or to check only the last `RunNumber`:

```
DELETE M
FROM
    Inventory_Databases_Master M
    LEFT JOIN
        (
            SELECT
                SQLInstanceName
                , DatabaseName
            FROM Inventory_Databases_DailyUpdate D
            WHERE
                D.RunNumber =
                    (
                        SELECT MAX(RunNumber)
                        FROM [Inventory_Databases_DailyUpdate]
                    )
        ) D
    ON
        M.SQLInstanceName = D.SQLInstanceName
        AND M.DatabaseName = D.DatabaseName
WHERE D.DatabaseName IS NULL
```

Comment: Thanks first. Yes using D.DatabaseName as NULL deletes nothing. Without  this, all 25 rows get deleted except the row with DatabaseName "hi".....However, I need opposite that these 25 rows should remain and only the "hi" row should get deleted.

Comment: Does the amended query give you what you're looking for?

Comment: The amended query deletes nothing.

Comment: If you try it as a `SELECT` that might reveal what's going on - if 'hi' is not in `D` then `D.DatabaseName` should be `NULL`.

Comment: Second amended query deletes everything from table except those 25 rows.

Comment: Why shouldn't it? Something to do with `MAX(RunNumber)`?

Comment: I hardcoded 'MAX(RunNumber)' as its value as 11, still the same issue.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/161328/discussion-between-channdeep-singh-and-chris-mack).

Comment: I amended the `WHERE` clause, which should fix it as per the SQL statements in your OP.